# gitlab nodejs api - retrieve all repositories for user

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, gitlab-api

I cannot figure out the way how to simply retrieve all repositories for my user on gitlab.

I'm trying to use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitlab

So for gitlab: Repositories=Projects

Here is how I try to use the gitlab package:

```coffee
options = 
    owned: true
    simple: true
    # membership: true
    # maxPages: 1
    # per_page: 1
try 
    projects = await gitlab.Projects.all(options)
    printSuccess "checkAccess Success!"
    log "typeof projects: " + typeof projects
    log "projects.length: " + projects.length
    olog projects
catch err
    printError "checkAccess Error!"
    olog service
    olog err
return true
```

The request is a success. Just the projects is always an empty array.

The only way I receive projects is when I donot state `owned:true`.
Then the request takes some time and returns any public projects it finds.

---

Funny is when stating `membership:true` but not `owned:true` it still returns an empty array...

Also funny is that when trying

```coffee
users = await gitlab.Users.all()
```

it always fails with `403 Forbidden`.

---

I've created various accessTokens one of them even with access to all of the scopes. For all the same behaviour occurs.

I have created a private and a public repository for my user to test this. So it definately should find these.

---

I also assume that the accessTokens are not the problem, as I get "401 Unauthorized" when I use an invalid one and the empty array when I use my valid one.

Also I assume that my accessToken is identifying my user so gitlab should know that the task is to retrieve all projects within my users' scope which are owned by my user.

Does anyone know how it works. I really donot understand what is going on and why it just would not work. Also yet I did not find anything helpful inside the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem.

When creating the gitlab access Object at first, it won't throw an error if the accessToken is `null`.

In this case we will not have a user and will have public access to repositories.